# How to use a private NPM Package in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, npm

I'm using NPM to create a package which contains typescript classes and methods that are used both in my front-end UI (angular) as well as in my backend (mostly google cloud functions).

While I can install the test package in VSCode where I am writing and testing my functions, when I try to deploy to Google Firebase Cloud functions (using `firebase deploy --only functions`, the deploy fails, saying in can't find my NPM package.  If I make the package public, it works as expected, but I would really prefer not to make the NPM package public.

Is there some workaround?